# Express middleware only if route matches later

Tags: node.js, express

I want to have protected and unprotected routes, and make it so that a request to an undefined route will return a 404 even in the case that the user is unauthenticated. The problem I have is that the authentication middleware runs on all routes except those defined before it, so any undefined routes return an authentication failure instead of a 404. Here's an example of the problem:

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('unprotected route');
});

// best auth ever
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.body.token) {
    return next();
  }

  res.send('auth failed');
});

router.get('/protected', function(req, res) {
  res.send('protected route');
});

/// catch 404
router.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});

app.use('/', router);
```

In this case, a request without a token to a random route (e.g. /whatever) will return 'auth failed' rather than a 404. How do you resolve this in Express?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to just move the authentication middleware into the route(s) before the route handlers:

```
// best auth ever
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if(req.body.token) {
    return next();
  }

  res.send('auth failed');
}

router.get('/protected', checkAuth, function(req, res) {
  res.send('protected route');
});
```

You could even do this to a group of routes by defining all of the routes in a separate router and then doing something like `router.use('/api', checkAuth, apiRouter)`.

Also, by default Express will respond with a 404 if no route matches, so you don't need to explicitly send it.

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks for the quick reply. Is it possible to have it work like this when mounting a router? If I do something like:

app.use('/', checkAuth, protectedRouter)

it still acts like my original example

Comment: The suggestion for a group of routes works, but only if it has a different prefix. Is it possible to have it also mounted under '/'

Comment: No, because as you said, it would be effectively the same thing you have in your original code snippet. You can either put the middleware on each route you want to protect if they are not grouped into a separate router, or only use the middleware when mounting a router on a separate path.